# connecting to a read-only Access db from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, ms-jet-ace

I have been a long-time visitor to stackoverflow, but this is my first question.

I'm trying to query an Access 2010 database in a folder to which the user has only read-only access.

```
     strDBPath = <full path of accdb>

     Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
     myConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _ 
                 "Mode=Read; Data Source=" & strDBPath

     Set myRS = New ADODB.Recordset
     myRS.ActiveConnection = myConn
```

The myConn.Open line gives a "file currently in use" error. If I move the accdb to a folder that the user can write, the code runs fine.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: The reason for the error is that it is trying to create the ".ldb' file (tracks users) for the database you are opening.  Can you implement user-level security and place in another folder?  Also, possibly have another database in a non-readonly folder with linked tables (or views) that would make it read-only.

Comment: Try connecting using DAO instead of ADO (i.e. you need to reference the 'Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database engine Object')

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn OP claims they are using accdb so there is no user level security option available, right? (Also the file being created is the `laccdb` file)

Comment: @steveo40 both ADO and DAO will try to create the laccdb file when you open a connection to the accdb.

Comment: @Brad - Yep, but either way, you should be able to have multiple users.  I thought it was worth a go, given I've had similar things working in both cases.

Comment: Actually, ignore me.  I hadn't read the question properly about the folder being read only

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! Even with the linked accdb in a r/w folder I get the same error (it quotes the original file)... As much as I see now, I'll have to provide r/w access for the folder to the users.

Answer (score 0):

Wie have also a connection with an Access DB but im quite sure we have also write permissions on the folder.

The Code we use is here.

```
   Dim DB As DAO.Database
   Dim QRY As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset
   Public Ersteller As String

   'Prüft die Verbindung zur DB
   Public Function OpenDB() As Integer

      'Informationen über Database'
      Dim Database As Variant
      Database = Worksheets("Anträge").Range("B3").Value

      'Check Datenbank Verbindung
      On Error Resume Next
      Set DB = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120").OpenDatabase(Database)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          MsgBox "Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank möglich!"
      End If
      OpenDB = Err.Number

   End Function
```

Mayebe it helps. :)

Comment: thanks but the point was to read from the DB in a read-only folder

Answer (score 0):

Access to database in a read only folder is possible (of course Mode=Read) but only if this database is not used by any other user (it means there is no .ldb file). But then, there is only one user able to have an access. So anyone calling database (even if it is done by excel) locking it for any others.
:-(